# Free cloud storage app for android

Tags: android, cloud-storage

I am looking for a free cloud storage app other than Google Drive, One Drive, and Dropbox. By free I mean the 5 or 10 GB free usage we get while sign up. I will tell my needs.

1. The app should be small in size. (I didn't select One Drive, Dropbox and some other apps due to its large size.)
2. I am not looking for a backup and restore app.
3. A feature to hide files and folders.
4. Smooth uploading and downloading.
5. It must be secure.
6. No ads.

In short I need an app same as Google Drive with hide facility. Can anyone suggest me a good cloud storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mega (https://mega.nz/) is free and offers 50GB of space, they also provide an android and ios app.